# Loading data to fill a table from a csv file with multicolumn header

Tags: tables, formatting, csvsimple

I'm trying to create a table that looks like this [image].

Currently I'm doing this ...

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Patch}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{ACES RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Display RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Display xyY}} \\ \hline
        \textbf{N1} & 1.8233 & 1.8233 & 1.8233 & 0.9243 & 0.8651 & 0.9013 & 0.3217 & 0.3377 & 34.4858 \\ \hline
        \textbf{N2} & 0.2753 & 0.2753 & 0.2753 & 0.5383 & 0.5038 & 0.5249 & 0.3217 & 0.3377 & 8.4552  \\ \hline
        \textbf{N3} & 0.0898 & 0.0898 & 0.0898 & 0.2804 & 0.2625 & 0.2734 & 0.3217 & 0.3377 & 1.5514  \\ \hline
        \textbf{R}  & 0.4689 & 0.1193 & 0.0417 & 0.8046 & 0.2227 & 0.1795 & 0.6413 & 0.3307 & 6.4488  \\ \hline
        \textbf{G}  & 0.339  & 0.8068 & 0.0936 & 0.4335 & 0.8036 & 0.2434 & 0.3046 & 0.624  & 20.8422 \\ \hline
        \textbf{B}  & 0.2162 & 0.133  & 0.8711 & 0.1707 & 0.1503 & 0.8215 & 0.1562 & 0.0692 & 2.3365  \\ \hline
        \textbf{C}  & 0.5187 & 0.9138 & 1.0432 & 0.4332 & 0.8028 & 0.8406 & 0.2269 & 0.3404 & 22.8164 \\ \hline
        \textbf{M}  & 0.58   & 0.2096 & 0.9086 & 0.808  & 0.2134 & 0.8294 & 0.333  & 0.1596 & 8.4349  \\ \hline
        \textbf{Y}  & 0.8237 & 0.9378 & 0.0855 & 0.8654 & 0.8096 & 0.2487 & 0.4338 & 0.5187 & 26.9923 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have many tables to create that all contain the same number and titled rows and columns (e.g. the bold stuff in the example above is the same for all tables).  Unfortunately, building each table is tedious.

I'm trying to figure out how I can use csvsimple to load the variable values in the table from a .csv file, but I can't seem to figure out how to the multicolumn and header rows to work.

I'm thinking each csv file would be formatted like this:

```
1.8233,1.8233,1.8233,0.9243,0.8651,0.9013,0.3217,0.3377,34.4858
0.2753,0.2753,0.2753,0.5383,0.5038,0.5249,0.3217,0.3377,8.4552
0.0898,0.0898,0.0898,0.2804,0.2625,0.2734,0.3217,0.3377,1.5514
0.4689,0.1193,0.0417,0.8046,0.2227,0.1795,0.6413,0.3307,6.4488
0.339,0.8068,0.0936,0.4335,0.8036,0.2434,0.3046,0.624,20.8422
0.2162,0.133,0.8711,0.1707,0.1503,0.8215,0.1562,0.0692,2.3365
0.5187,0.9138,1.0432,0.4332,0.8028,0.8406,0.2269,0.3404,22.8164
0.58,0.2096,0.9086,0.808,0.2134,0.8294,0.333,0.1596,8.4349
0.8237,0.9378,0.0855,0.8654,0.8096,0.2487,0.4338,0.5187,26.9923
```

Comment: My personal approach to this kind of problems is to write a small python¹ script that transforms the cvs file into a ready-made LaTeX table and then `\input` that table. ¹Of course, you can use a different scripting language when you know it better.

Comment: @jknappen sure I could do this but part of what I’m trying to avoid is large sections of code being dedicated to just building a table.  I was planning on ultimately making a macro that I could reuse.

Comment: Another very simple way to import data from a csv file into LaTeX is by generating the code for table rows in Excel or other Office Suites. Just concatenate the columns by applying the formula `=TEXTJOIN(" & ",FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1:F1),CHAR(9),""))` to each table row and paste the data into your LaTeX table environment. SUBSTITUTE and TRIM remove trailing spaces and tabs. It is also not hard to make it work with multirow and multicolumn cells by adding LaTeX commands in a csv file. I can write a full-fledged answer if anybody is interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first solution is with `booktabs` and without vertical rules (I think the table looks better this way); the second one is like the OP's image.

*Edit:* I've added a third example which doesn't use `siunitx`, to show the difference to the OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
    1.8233,1.8233,1.8233,0.9243,0.8651,0.9013,0.3217,0.3377,34.4858
    0.2753,0.2753,0.2753,0.5383,0.5038,0.5249,0.3217,0.3377,8.4552
    0.0898,0.0898,0.0898,0.2804,0.2625,0.2734,0.3217,0.3377,1.5514
    0.4689,0.1193,0.0417,0.8046,0.2227,0.1795,0.6413,0.3307,6.4488
    0.339,0.8068,0.0936,0.4335,0.8036,0.2434,0.3046,0.624,20.8422
    0.2162,0.133,0.8711,0.1707,0.1503,0.8215,0.1562,0.0692,2.3365
    0.5187,0.9138,1.0432,0.4332,0.8028,0.8406,0.2269,0.3404,22.8164
    0.58,0.2096,0.9086,0.808,0.2134,0.8294,0.333,0.1596,8.4349
    0.8237,0.9378,0.0855,0.8654,0.8096,0.2487,0.4338,0.5187,26.9923 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \caption{The best}
        \centering\tiny\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4} 
        \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}c}
            \toprule
            Patch\\\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
            N1\\ N2\\ N3\\ R\\ G\\ B\\ C\\ M\\ Y\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
        \csvloop{file=mydata.csv, no head, 
            before reading=\centering%\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
            ,
            tabular={c@{}*8{S[table-format=1.4]}S[table-format=2.4]},
            table head=\toprule & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{ACES RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Display RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Display xyY}}\\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}, command=&\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix, table foot=\bottomrule}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \caption{The not-so-beautiful}
        \centering\tiny\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}c|}
            \hline
            Patch\\\hline
            N1\\\hline N2\\\hline N3\\\hline 
            R\\\hline G\\\hline B\\\hline
            C\\\hline M\\\hline Y\\\hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \csvloop{file=mydata.csv, no head, 
            before reading=\centering%\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
            ,
            tabular={c@{}*8{S[table-format=1.4]|}S[table-format=2.4]|},
            table head=\hline & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{ACES RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Display RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Display xyY}}\\
            \hline, 
            command=&\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix,
            late after line=\\\hline}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \caption{The ugly}
        \centering\tiny\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}c|}
            \hline
            Patch\\\hline
            N1\\\hline N2\\\hline N3\\\hline 
            R\\\hline G\\\hline B\\\hline
            C\\\hline M\\\hline Y\\\hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \csvloop{file=mydata.csv, no head, 
            tabular={*9{l|}},
            table head=\hline \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{ACES RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Display RGB}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Display xyY}}\\
            \hline, 
            command=\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix,
            late after line=\\\hline}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why use `before reading=\centering\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center` instead of just `before reading=\centering` which doesn't require `siunitx`?

Comment: @agf1997 `\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}` isn't necessary, but I used `siunitx` to better aling the columns, see  column types `S[table-format=...]`.

Comment: @agf1997 Please look at my renewed answer, the "ugly" example is without `siunitx`, please note the alignment of the last column.

Comment: yes this is very helpful.  Thank you so much